# static table view works in iOS6 but not iOS5

Tags: ios5, ios6, uitableview

I have searched for hours and hours and found many hints but not the solution. I have a very simple tableview with static cells. I am following the Apple documentation. I am not using storyboard, I have unchecked autolayout, set document versioning to iOS5. It works just fine in iOS6, but cells are NIL in iOS5 hence it will crash.

The cells are done in IB, I have the properties wired up, I have cell identifiers (actually not needed but does not make a difference). The log statement returns (null) in iOS5 but returns correctly a cell in iOS6.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.section == 0 ) {

        if (indexPath.row ==0) {

        cell0.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        NSLog(@"description = %@",[cell0 description]);
        return cell0;
        }
        if (indexPath.row ==1) {

        cell1.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        return cell1;
        }
        if (indexPath.row ==2) {

            cell2.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            return cell2;
        }
        if (indexPath.row ==3) {

            cell3.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            return cell3;
        }
    }
    cell4.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell4;
}
```

Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction. I know it must be simple but it drives me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with following code snippet it will work in ios5.

if (indexPath.section == 0 ) {

```
    if (indexPath.row ==0) {

    UITableViewCell *cell0 = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell0"];

    cell0.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    NSLog(@"description = %@",[cell0 description]);
    return cell0;

    if (indexPath.row ==1) {

    UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell1"];

    cell1.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell1;
    }

    if (indexPath.row ==2) {

    UITableViewCell *cell2 = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell2"];
        cell2.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        return cell2;
    }

   if (indexPath.row ==3) {

      UITableViewCell *cell3 = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell3"];
        cell3.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        return cell3;
    }

   UITableViewCell *cell4 = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell4"];
   cell4.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
   return cell4;
```

}

Comment: Martin, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I am getting exact same error message and NSLOG returns null for the description of the cell.

Comment: UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell1"];  replace this method with   UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell1" forIndexPath: indexpath.row];   or  UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell1" forIndex: index]; // I dont know the exact method. try atleast this one

Comment: I know that this method changed between iOS5 and 6. However I should not need any reusable cell as in a static view there is nothing to be reused (all custom cells are different)

Answer (score 0):

when you used dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: it can return nil if there are no cells created. You need to alloc and init your own cell at this point.

Comment: Bryce, I want to use my code above. That is what Apple writes in their docu for non-storyboard static table views. And as said, works perfectly in iOS6 but funny enough not in iOS5 despite I did exactly what the docu says. I guess it is a problem that I used a later xcode than the version Apple used in their older document. So something is not wired up correctly. Works fine in simulator and on device for iOS6, crashes on both with empty cells in iOS5

Comment: I'm guessing you'll see the same problem in the simulator if you start simulating memory warnings. If you think it's a bug "in the wiring." I'd recommend using MARTIN's advice rather than using storyboards.